# how to get value member of combobox which is created using foreach loop

Tags: c#

How can I get a value member of combobox which is created using foreach loop? It does not show the value member.

My code below:

```
DataSet dsLoadWorkHourId = new DataSet();
dsLoadWorkHourId = Workhour.LoadWorkId();
foreach (DataRow row in dsLoadWorkHourId.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    cmbWorkHourId.Items.Add(row["SHIFT"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should rather do like this

```
 DataSet dsLoadWorkHourId = new DataSet();
 dsLoadWorkHourId = Workhour.LoadWorkId();
cmbWorkHourID.DataSource = dsLoadWorkHourId.Tables[0]
cmbWorkHourID.DisplayMember = "SHIFT";
cmbWorkHourID.ValueMember = "SHIFTID"; //Use the ID column name here
```

If you want to display ID as display member than

```
 DataSet dsLoadWorkHourId = new DataSet();
 dsLoadWorkHourId = Workhour.LoadWorkId();
cmbWorkHourID.DataSource = dsLoadWorkHourId.Tables[0]
cmbWorkHourID.DisplayMember = "SHIFTID"; //use the ID column name here
cmbWorkHourID.ValueMember = "SHIFTID"; //Use the ID column name here
```

Comment: thanx buddy.Actually i am using same dataset for many comboboxes and if i change any one of them i will apply to all comboboxes. thats why this combobox  i have to make using loop.But now i need its value member too.

Comment: @Prakash: Then why dont you use BindingContext in between.